# Which MEAN Generator - javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, web

I'm just a newbie in this field, I mean at the development of web apps using javascript.

I was learning how to use NodeJS + express on the backend, but at the same time I was trying to go ahead with the use of AngularJS on the front-end. I also installed yeoman for the scaffolding of the app; actually I was using generator-angularexpress.

So, my question is: which generator do you consider to be the best one for the scaffolding of the web app, keeping in mind that I want to build a MEAN stack?

Thank you folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best available mean stack generator(as on date and as per me) : https://npmjs.org/package/generator-mean

Answer (score 2):

If you are just getting started. I'd recommend angular-express-seed: https://github.com/btford/angular-express-seed

And here is a related tutorial using the seed project to build a blog http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comprehensive comparison of generators that use Angular.JS.

http://www.dancancro.com/comparison-of-angularjs-application-starters/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Angularjs Fullstack Generator](http://angular-fullstack.github.io/generator-angular-fullstack/index.html) after reading and exploring the options mentioned in this [article](https://medium.com/@martunta/choosing-the-seed-for-mean-stack-70eb989ef902#.2znga6gfd).